# RMarkdown Beamer automatically add escape in front of curly braces

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating a beamer presentation file in PDF format using RMarkdown. I have trouble because escape `\` is automatically added when I use latex command `\tiny{blahblah} \small`. A potential get around would be using `\begin{tiny}` and `\end{tiny}` instead, but that changes line which I do not want (in other words, I want to change the font size in the same line in beamer). The first bullet in the attached picture is what I want, which I manually created, and the second bullet is what rmd produces.

Here's the YAML header

```
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: "pdflatex"
    includes:
      in_header: header_pagenum.tex
  ioslides_presentation: default
  slidy_presentation: default
```

and the header tex file is the following:

```
setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

I'm not sure if this info is enough to detect the problem (I'd be happy to share more info if needed), but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: try `{\tiny blah blah}`

Comment: I don't quite get what's happening, but I just removed all the curly braces and it works.